# tty1 stuck on showing systemd instead of login prompt

Tags: tty

I was booting Debian 10.4, and it worked fine. Now I have found out, that tty1 is hanging on showing systemd and doesn't move to login prompt. ttys 2-7 work like normal.

`systemctl enable getty@tty1.service` didn't work.

Is it a bug or a feature? If it is a bug, how to fix it?

Comment: Why are you *telling* us this, you also have a *question*?

Comment: Is it a bug or a feature? If it is a bug, how to fix it?